# Insert data from another table as a foreign key

Tags: sql

There are two tables.

Table 1

```
           expenseID | description | generatedBy | notifyWho | frequencyGeneration
              1      | Advance Pay | Conductor   | Clerk     | Once a week
              2      | Contract Pay| Conductor   | Clerk     | Contract Period
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhBWP.png)

Table 2

```
       divExpenseID |   divNo     | expenseID   |descriptions| date       | amount   | status
              1     |     1       |   1         | Clerk      | 2020-01-11 | 5000     | Pending
              2     |     1       |   1         | Clerk      | 2020-01-11 | 2000     | Active
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua9wn.png)

In this, I entered data to table 1 first, then I inserted data to table 2 except expenseID in table 2. I want to get data for expenseID using table 1.

As an example, when I insert data to **divExpenseID, divNo, descriptions, date, amount, status** expenseID should be updated automatically from table 1.

What is the query for that, is it better if I write only one query for above operation.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: On which basis  _expenseID should be updated automatically from table 1_ ? can you elaborate more on this.

Answer (score -1):

The table 1 description tells that expenseID data type is char, but the datas you stored in expenseID are number.

I suggest you change the data type of expenseID to integer and use the AUTO_INCREMENT machanism for this field.

After each the insertion of table 1 is completted then you can get the AUTO_INCREMENT id of the last row that has been inserted or updated in a table 1 by using

> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: First i insert data to expenses table(table 1).  expensesID is the primary key of table 1. So it is the foreign key for divisionexpenses table (table 2). When i insert data to table 2 i only insert data for  divExpenseID |   divNo     | descriptions| date       | amount   | status . I dont insert data for expensesID. i want to get that value from table 1 automatically.